# How to get Instagram Profile Picture's API?

Tags: node.js, api, instagram

Who can explain to me what is Instagram DP API, how to get it. I know that it is used for downloading DP, but how to get it. It must look like a `token` I believe.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply a get request. You can send with fetch or axios.

API: https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1

Example with node.js

with Axios
First install axios with npm

```
npm i axios
```

then

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.get('https://www.instagram.com/nil.ooy/?__a=1').then(res=> {
    console.log(res.data.graphql.user.profile_pic_url)
    // Do stuffs
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that code you typed above, actually, I'm Developing a Telegram Bot, I came across with a sample one which I found due to my research and for running the bot, it requires a token of telegram's bot of course and Instagram Display Picture API, where I put this ```https://www.instagram.com/nil.ooy/?__a=1```, but that was wrong, so I think it must be a token like tokens of Telegram Bots.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram shut down its public API. Meaning, third-party apps can no longer access the API from Instagram without permission. Third-party apps now need to be approved by Instagram before they can access the API